# How to configure Gradle for Spring in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, mongodb, gradle

I am getting an error when i use to configure Gradle in Eclipse
I have also tried on different systems.
Is it x86 or x64 dependant ?

Listner Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'  
apply plugin: 'war'  
apply plugin: 'eclipse'  

repositories {  
   mavenCentral()  
}  

dependencies {  
    compile  'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile  'org.springframework:spring-jms:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile  'org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.12.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.+'
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.12.4'  
}
```

Sender Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'  
apply plugin: 'war'  
apply plugin: 'eclipse'  

repositories {  
   mavenCentral()  
}  

dependencies {  
    compile  'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile  'org.springframework:spring-jms:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile  'org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.12.0'  
}
```

build.gradle

I need another build automation tool that builds upon the concepts of Apache Ant and Apache Maven and introduces a Groovy-based domain-specific language (DSL) instead of the more traditional XML form of declaring the project configuration

Comment: I want to convert XML to POJO

Comment: What error? Does your project build well from command line? Have you tried using IntelliJ IDEA instead of Eclipse?

Comment: Do your projects build successfully from the command line? If they don't, you need to fix that before complicating the situation further by adding an IDE. And as topr wrote, you'll have to provide us with any error messages.